# How to bind model correctly?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

If the user enters input into a inputfield of a Custom Control and the value is submitted, the requirement ist to add this value to the model and to rerender the view.

Debuging shows that the value is added to the model successfully but the view is not getting rerendered:

**App.controller.js**

```
onInit: function() {

  // set mock model
  var sPath = sap.ui.require.toUrl("xxx/custom") + "/feed.json";
  var oModel = new JSONModel(sPath);
  this.getView().setModel(oModel);

  var oPage = this.getView().byId("xx-content");

  var oCustomControl = new CustomControl("cc",{
    messages: "{/data}"
  });

  oPage.addContent(oCustomControl);
}
```

**CustomControl.js**

```
...
  _onMessageAdd: function (oEvent) {
    var model = sap.ui.getCore().byId("cc").getModel().getProperty("/data");

    var oData = {
      text: "abc", text2: ["abc", "def"]
    }

    model.push(oData);

...
```

Comment: you should not use access to the parent model in a custom control, but rather send the data from the model using the custom control's properties. Your approach will work, but this is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the model that you are updating the property. So, just add this function call after "model.push":

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("cc").getModel().setProperty("/data", model);
```